# Exception in Pom.xml SPring Starter project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml, new-project

I created a project with Spring Starter Project, but my `pom.xml` gives me this exception:

```
org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.getManifest(
    org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject, org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiveConfiguration)
```

Comment: Please share your pom.xml with us.

Comment: The code shown is not an exception. Please post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your eclipse m2e connectors by

Help -> Install New Software -> paste this link and install http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/0.17.2/N/LATEST/